# www subdomain works but others don't

Tags: nginx, subdomain, gunicorn

I encountered a problem with nginx I do not understand.

I am able to correctly setup and call `www.example.tech` and `example.tech`.

However when adding another subdomain like `survey.example.tld` to the list the other two still work but `survey.example.tld` does not.

In chrome I get the following error message when trying to call `http://survey.example.tech/`:

> This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in
> survey.example.tech. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I am pretty sure there is no typo in it because I triple checked. Also, `www.example.tech` and `example.tech` still work.

I use nginx to forward requests to a gunicorn/flask app.

Therefore I put my config into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/survey.example.tech 

server {    
    server_name example.tech www.example.tech survey.example.tech;
    
    location /static {
        alias /opt/example.tech/my-domain-Survey-Website/static;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8003;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # Max file size allowed for upload by user. Here 1M = 1 Megabyte
        client_max_body_size 1M;
        
        # prevents warning messages when setting up let's encrypt
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
        
        # Enable Websocket by adding these two options
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

and the corresponding service in `/etc/systemd/system`

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-my-domain-survey-flask.service 
[Unit]
Description = gunicorn for my-domain website
After = network.target

[Service]
Environment=LOG_PATH=/opt/example.tech/example.tech-Survey-Website/gunicorn-logs
User = ubuntu
Group = ubuntu
WorkingDirectory = /opt/example.tech/example.tech-Survey-Website
ExecStart = /opt/example.tech/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8003 -w 1 --log-level debug --access-logfile ${LOG_PATH}/access-logfile.log --error-logfile ${LOG_PATH}/error.log  --capture-output run_survey_website:app

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

When I run this everything works fine except for `survey.example.tech`.

What is happening here? Am I missunderstanding the setup of subdomains with nginx?

Comment: The error is indicating a problem with your DNS and not your Nginx server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nginx configuration is fine.

You need to add a DNS record for `survey.example.tech` that points to the IP address of your server.